# How can i cast between void* and boost shared ptr

Tags: c++, boost, casting, shared-ptr, void-pointers

I've got these lines:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> A_SPtr;
void *f(void* var){ ...
```

and i want to be able to do something like this:

```
A_SPtr instance = (void*)(var);
```

how can i do it? 
Also, how can i cast the other way around meaning from the shared_ptr to void*?

Comment: The purpose of a smart pointer is to own heap allocated memory. e.g. `A_SPtr instance = new A();`

Comment: from the shared_ptr to void - void* ptr = s_ptr.get();

Comment: @AJG85 the pointer was allocated outside of the function, and i want to pass it as a void* and then turn it back again to the shared_ptr inside the function

Comment: What is your actual use case? There are several different ways to do this (cast a pointer to the shared pointer to a `void *`, use `shared_from_this`, and others) and the right way depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @David Schwartz this method f is a routine of a thread (using pthread) which receives a shared pointer in the form of void* and then i want to cast it back to the shared pointer in order to use its class's methods

Comment: Can you change the function signature to take a boost::shared_ptr<A> by value? That's usually how you want to pass these objects around. Never by reference and never by removing the fact that's it's a shared pointer unless the function f() only needs to access the pointer and not take shared ownership or pass shared ownership to another object.

Comment: @cppguy i can't since its a thread method meant to be sent to pthread_create which receives a method which returns and get void*

Comment: do yourself a favor and use boost::thread if you can. it makes passing arbitrary data to a thread trivial

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just cast pointers to shared pointers to and from `void *`.

1. `shared_ptr` to `void *`:

   ```
   f (reinterpret_cast<void *>;(&A_SPtr));
   ```
2. `void *` back to `shared_ptr`:

   ```
   A_SPtr instance = * reinterpret_cast(boost::shared_ptr<A>*)(var);
   ```

**CAUTION:** This passes a pointer to the shared pointer to the thread. This will not work if the shared pointer does not remain in existence through the life of the thread function – otherwise, the thread will have a pointer to an object (the shared pointer) that no longer exists. If you cannot meet that requirement, pass a pointer to a **new** shared_ptr and `delete` it when the thread is done with it. (Or use `boost:bind` which works with shared pointers directly.)

Comment: @David Schwartz there was someone who suggested calling var.get() in order to get its void* ... do you know if it works? Also, did you mean to write f (reinterpret_cast<void *>(&var)); ?

Comment: The `get` function gets the pointer to the object from the shared pointer. The question asks how to get the shared pointer back. (That's why I asked what the use case was. You said "i want to cast it back to the shared pointer".) Really though, you should just use [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_member_pointers).

Comment: This is correct but kind of dangerous because there's a chance the shared pointer object could be out of scope before the thread starts up

Comment: @cppguy: I agree. You should probably create a `new` shared_ptr to pass to the thread and have the thread `delete` it when it's done. Or, better yet, use boost::bind which does all that for you.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Can you give an example of how to use `boost::bind`? It appears that you can't simple cast a boost bound function to a plain function pointer.

Comment: @dividebyzero I can't really fit the answer in a comment. Can you ask your own question?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Can you give just two lines of code explaining "pass a pointer to a new shared_ptr and delete".

Comment: @user18853 `reinterpret_cast<void*>(new std::shared_ptr<A>(A_SPtr))` and pass it to the thread. In the thread, you cast it back to `std::shared_ptr<A>*` and `delete` it when you're done with it.

Comment: So by allocating shared_ptr on Heap you are avoiding deletion of object? Am I correct?

Comment: @user18853 Correct. And this is a common pattern to pass something to a thread. You allocate it on the heap, pass the thread a pointer to it, the thread casts the pointer back to the correct type, and deletes it when it's done with it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz assuming `A` is threadsafe, if I have a method `std::shared_ptr<A> blah(){...}` is it save to do `void* resPtr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(new std::shared_ptr<A>(blah()));`, pass resPtr to a different thread, then eventually in that thread do `delete (std::shared_ptr<A>*)resPtr;` like you said? If I do this does it make a duplicate of my object returned from `blah()` using a copy constructor? Or does it keep the original pointer? I'm using an external library that has `blah()` but doesn't have a copy constructor defined for `A`, so I'm worried about how valid this is.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. No copy would ever be made.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're sure it's okay to assume ownership of the `void*` passed to you in f, that the `void*` does in fact refer to an `A` object, and you know the correct way to clean up, then you can just go ahead and use a smart pointer to assume ownership:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> A_SPtr;

void *f(void *var){
    A_SPtr instance(static_cast<A*>(var));
}
```

---

Edit: It's not clear from the question, but some comments indicate that your actually trying to pass a smart pointer through a 'generic' interface that uses `void*`. You do this the same way you'd do it for any type:

```
void *f(void *var){
    A_SPtr *instance = static_cast<A_SPtr *>(var);
}
```

And you pass the pointer like:

```
A_SPtr a;
f(&a);
```

As with any pointer you must ensure that the object's lifetime is sufficient for the pointer to be valid when `f` receives it.